# Create multiple histograms, grouped by user from a large, single dataset in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a large dataset, df:

```
  User              duration

  amy                582         
  amy                27
  amy                592
  amy                16
  amy                250
  tom                33
  tom                10
  tom                40
  tom                100
```

I would like to group by User, and then create a histogram for each User:

```
 amy (histogram image)


 tom (histogram image)
```

Here is the dput:

```
structure(list(User = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("amy", "tom"), class = "factor"), duration = c(582L, 
27L, 592L, 16L, 250L, 33L, 10L, 40L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I know how to create a histogram in Python using the following code:, but how do I create multiple histograms in python, grouping by the User. Should I create a dictionary?

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 df = (amy[582,27, 592, 16, 250], tom[33,10,40,100])
 num_bins = 20
 n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
 plt.show()
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':['amy', 'amy','amy','amy','amy', 'tom', 'tom', 'tom','tom',],
              'duration': [582, 27, 592, 16, 250, 33, 10, 40, 100]})

ax = df['duration'].hist(by=df['user'])

for a in ax.flatten():
    a.set_xlabel("duration")
    a.set_ylabel("frequency")
```

[image]

Comment: let me try. Thank you